# Generic redirects

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-301

I've recently moved host's, whomever owned our ip previously obviously ran some kind of forum becasue we are receiving a significant amount of 404 traffic for .*/forums/ is there a way to regex a 301 redirect to forward traffic looking for .*/forums/ to an actual page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want [`RedirectMatch`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch).